# If I have too much fresh pasta, should I cook it up or store it as is?

Tags: pasta, refrigerator

I overestimated the amount of fresh ravioli (cheese and wild mushroom, if it matters) I'd need when buying from the local pasta shop, and ended up only cooking half of it for our meal.

Assuming we'll have the rest sometime later this week, is it best to cook up the rest and put it in the fridge, or to leave it raw? And would it be better to put it in the freezer, or is the fridge okay if it's not going to be more than a few days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I make a lot of fresh pasta, both filled and non-filled.  I always freeze immediately, even if I am going to use it a few hours later. Uncooked, fresh pasta (filled or not) freezes very well.  Do this in a single layer.  Once frozen move to zip top bags or other container.  I freeze because fresh pasta, especially filled, can get sticky...sticking to the plate it is on, or to itself. It's just easier to work with if you freeze it.  Quality is not compromised, and you can toss in boiling water in its frozen state when you are ready to cook it.

Comment: How long can you freeze it for?

Comment: @Thomo It will be "safe" to eat indefinitely. If you have a frost-free freezer, it will likely suffer *quality* degradation after a 2-3 months.

Comment: I generally agree with @Catija.  If you can remove air from the bag or container, it can last a bit longer than otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it uncooked, and store in the fridge. Put it in an airtight bag so it doesn't dry out.

As for stuffed pasta: you would keep cheese and mushrooms for a few days, right?

I might stick it in the deep chill compartment (meat drawer) of the fridge side, but not freeze, if I were worried about the filling.